# How to do a SQL CASE query?

Tags: sql, if-statement, mariadb, case

I try to do an Case query, but it is not showing the desired success.

```
SELECT
   t1.Id,   
     t1.amount,
     t2.Id,
     t1.singlePrice,                            
  CASE t1.number  
     WHEN NULL THEN t3.number
  END
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.fk_id
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 t3 ON t1.number = t3.number
WHERE t2.id = 487
```

Usually all numbers are in Table3.
But in Table1 there are numbers which are not existing in Table3.
What I want:
If the number is found in Table3 => use number ob Table3 otherwise use ist from Table1.

Comment: What are you truing to do?  It looks like `COALESCE(t3.number, t1.numer)` (see: [1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/coalesce/)), but I am not sure if you want to do that....   Can you add input data, and desired output data (use [edit]),  so there will be no doubt on what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: In your case `ISNULL(t3.number, t1.number)` might do the job.

Comment: You have `JOIN TABLE3 t3 ON t1.number = t3.number`. So, "If the number is found in Table3 => use number of Table3 otherwise use ist from Table1" makes no sense, as you could just as well always show the number of table1. The number in table3 can be null or equal to the number in table1, it can never be different.

Answer (score 0):

you should check for t3.number is null

```
SELECT
   t1.Id,   
     t1.amount,
     t2.Id,
     t1.singlePrice,                            
  CASE WHEN t3.number  IS NULL
     THEN t1.numnber
     ELSE t3.number
  END
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.fk_id
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 t3 ON t1.number = t3.number
WHERE t2.id = 487
```

Also possible

```
SELECT
   t1.Id,   
     t1.amount,
     t2.Id,
     t1.singlePrice,                            
  COALESCE (t3.number, t1.numnber)
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.fk_id
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 t3 ON t1.number = t3.number
WHERE t2.id = 487
```